# Force page format with section title plus images

Tags: floats, scaling

I have to add an appendix to my thesis where I have to put some graphs for many objects. The appendix is structured with a section for each object containing a series of graphs. What I want to do is to force latex to put in each page the section title and the set of graphs. So latex have to resize all things to allow such thing. So

```
    \begin{appendices}
    \chapter{data}
    \section{obj1}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    ...
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    ...
    \end{figure}
    \section{obj2}
    ...
    ...
    \end{appendices}
```

and I want all in a page so, if images are too large, LaTeX have to resize them. A thing like resizebox will work for many figures? And if yes how can I resize them?

Comment: So it should just fit... regardless of what the output looks like... even if it should technically fit on (say) 2 pages, you want to squeeze it into less-than-one (due to the headings).

Comment: Yes. But there are problem like the flying around of section titles, so I was thinking about something that says to latex: the section title and the figures are one thing that has to be resized to fit a page.

Comment: Ok I have found the subfigure enviroment in the subcaption package to make all graphs "one thing". The problem is how to resize the entire figure enviroment that wrap all subfigures... Is possible to set the size of a figure (not of a \includegraphics)? resizebox doesn't work outside figure...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal that uses [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) to scale the collection of images to fit within some `max`imum `width` or `totalheight`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{First section}
\begingroup
  \centering
  \adjustbox{max totalheight = .55\textheight, max width = \textwidth}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      \includegraphics{example-image-a} \\ \\
      \includegraphics[scale=1.5]{example-image-b}
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \captionof{figure}{This is the first figure}
\endgroup

\clearpage

\section{Second section}
\begingroup
  \centering
  \adjustbox{max totalheight = .8\textheight, max width = \textwidth}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      \includegraphics{example-image-a} \\ \\
      \includegraphics[scale=1.5]{example-image-b} \\ \\
      \includegraphics[height=50pt]{example-image-c} \\ \\
      \includegraphics[scale=10]{example-image}
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \captionof{figure}{This is the second figure}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

You would adjust the length set for `max totalheight` to suit your needs (based on what is available on the page), and `max width` set to `\textwidth` makes sure your collage is not wider than the text block.

Note that using the above settings, the aspect ratio of the images are kept, which is a good thing.